# jquery ui accordion on hover text color

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to get the color of the accordion to change on hover only when the the section being hovered over is collapsed.

The closest I've gotten is this, which changes the text color ONLY when I hover over the text but not over the rest of the accordion element and it also changes the color when the section is active.

CSS:

```
.ui-accordion a:hover{
  color:blue
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h5>
        <a href="#">Section 1</a>
    </h5>
    <h5>
        <a href="#">Section 2</a>
    </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show the HTML in order to help with this.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the corresponding HTML ? Can you please include it in your post ?

Comment: Sorry... there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing from what I read are you trying to only have the color change to blue when it is not the open element?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/7jf7cngd/

I used `h3` in the example in the fiddle here which I took from jquery's site. Are you using `a`? jQuery adds `.ui-state-active` to the active one automatically so I took advantage of that.

```
.ui-accordion h3:not(.ui-state-active):hover{
  color:blue
}
```

Updated fiddle using the HTML you added: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/7jf7cngd/1/

```
.ui-accordion h5:not(.ui-state-active) a:hover{
  color:blue
}
```

Updated to include hovering over entire header: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/7jf7cngd/23/

```
.ui-accordion h5:not(.ui-state-active):hover a {
  color: blue
}
```

Comment: I added the complete jquery ui css to your fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/7jf7cngd/11/]. Your code works when only not active which is great but it also only works when hovering over the text.

Comment: Ok. Give me a min. Ran to get coffee. I'll update it.

Comment: @JoMojo updated answer. let me know if thats what you wanted.

Comment: @ AtheistP3ace Exactly what I wanted thanks... goto tell you being new to CSS it's not always easy!!

Comment: @JoMojo No problem. It can be confusing to new comers. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to apply hover to `.ui-accordion-header` and not for `.ui-accordion a` for **jQuery UI Accordion**. Do it as below

```
.ui-accordion-header:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```